# Can we write algorithms without conditional statements?

Tags: turing-machines

Regarding turing completeness, i read that for a language/machine to be turing complete it is required that it has some sort of conditional.

Consider the factorial problem, we would typically define the algorithm as

**Solution 1.**

```
int fact(int n)
{
if n == 0 then
 return 1;
else
 return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

An alternative would be to define the function fact as

**Solution 2.**

```
int fact(int n)
{
 if n == 0 then return 1;
 elseif n == 1 then return 1;
 elseif n == 2 then return 2;
 elseif n == 3 then return 6;
 ....
 all cases define as above
}
```

Also, another solution would be to have functions like:

**Solution 3.**

```
int fact0()
{
return 1;
}

int fact1()
{
return 1*fact0;
}

int fact2()
{
return 2*fact1;
}

int fact3()
{
return 3*fact2;
}
```

Then we would have an array of function pointers p which we would have to index according to the factorial we want to determine, such that p[0] points to fact0, p[1] points to fact1, and so forth.

I know that this might sound dumb, but it actually works! What makes solution 1. a valid argument to show that conditionals are required to compute the factorial?

Some additional thoughts on my part:
1. Is solution 1 the only true "algorithm"? Because the other 2 solutions to not seem to "compute" anything
2. Are conditionals required only because we dont know the results (or execution steps) of functions beforehand?

Thanks in advance